# CSS: How to "trim" the empty space when using clip-path?

Tags: html, css

When I use clip-path, it hides away some part of the image:
-webkit-clip-path: inset(165px 20px 46px 206px);
clip-path: inset(165px 20px 46px 206px);

But that doesn't shrink the image down to those dimensions.  I'm left with the desired part of the image, surrounded by a ton of whitespace.

So, assuming an image which is 250x227, and the above clip-path css, what additional css do I need to then trim away the excess whitespace while *not* mis-using the width and height css arguments?

Comment: Can you add your code? Or make a jsfiddle?

Comment: You can't AFAIK...

Comment: Denea, not everything needs a fiddle.  :P

Comment: Does the duplicate suggestion above solve your question?

Comment: Not quite the same I think, but that got me far enough to find a solution:

-webkit-clip-path: inset(3px 232px 213px 3px);margin-right: -232px;margin-bottom: -213;position: relative;top: -3px;left: -3px;

Comment: Even simpler: -webkit-clip-path: inset(165px 20px 46px 206px);position:relative;margin: -3px -232px -213px -3px; also works :)

Comment: Is it okay I vote to close it as a dupe?, as it shows where the space comes from, then, whether one use your fix or the other is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Up to you, though I think it's different enough.  If anyone wanted to submit ^^ as an answer, I'd take it.  :)